# Really quick and dirty solution for embedding webkit in a Swing UI?

Tags: java, swing, webkit

I am looking for a really quick and dirty solution for embedding webkit in a Swing application.

What I am looking for is a way to implement a panel that contains a webkit browser running some JavaScript that will be able to do one or more of the following:

- Call a Java function of the containing application
- Send JSON objects to the containing application

I would also like to have access to the DOM from my Java code.

Comment: Does "Get JDK7 from near future" count as quick'n'dirty? :)

Comment: @Esko `from __future__ impor...` oh wait, nevermind.

Comment: @Carson et. al: Just to update, seems like WebKit won't be embedded in JDK7 so better tune that timemachine to jump a bit further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JWebPane](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alex2d/archive/2008/12/jwebpane_projec_1.html) is allegedly going to do this for you, but it's [vaporware](http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/jwebpane-update/) for the time being. Your best bet might be to take a look at the [WebKit component in Qt Jambi](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/01/11/who-needs-a-browser-qt-jambi-just-got-one/) and use the [Swing bridge](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/QtJambi/QtJambiAwtBridge) to stick it in a Swing app.